# There was an error in the switching effect while combining videos using ffmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg

I want to give a conversion effect by connecting multiple files at once, but there is an error. How should I solve this problem?

code

```
ffmpeg -i /Users/andaegeun/Desktop/theirmood/theirmood/storage/app/public/videoAddAnimation/0.mp4 -i /Users/andaegeun/Desktop/theirmood/theirmood/storage/app/public/videoAddAnimation/1.mp4 -i /Users/andaegeun/Desktop/theirmood/theirmood/storage/app/public/videoAddAnimation/2.mp4 -i /Users/andaegeun/Desktop/theirmood/theirmood/storage/app/public/videoAddAnimation/3.mp4 -i /Users/andaegeun/Desktop/theirmood/theirmood/storage/app/public/videoAddAnimation/4.mp4 -i /Users/andaegeun/Desktop/theirmood/theirmood/storage/app/public/videoAddAnimation/5.mp4 -i /Users/andaegeun/Desktop/theirmood/theirmood/storage/app/public/videoAddAnimation/6.mp4 -i /Users/andaegeun/Desktop/theirmood/theirmood/storage/app/public/videoAddAnimation/7.mp4 -i /Users/andaegeun/Desktop/theirmood/theirmood/storage/app/public/videoAddAnimation/8.mp4 -i /Users/andaegeun/Desktop/theirmood/theirmood/storage/app/public/videoAddAnimation/9.mp4 -i /Users/andaegeun/Desktop/theirmood/theirmood/storage/app/public/videoAddAnimation/10.mp4 -i /Users/andaegeun/Desktop/theirmood/theirmood/storage/app/public/videoAddAnimation/11.mp4 -i /Users/andaegeun/Desktop/theirmood/theirmood/storage/app/public/videoAddAnimation/12.mp4 -i /Users/andaegeun/Desktop/theirmood/theirmood/storage/app/public/videoAddAnimation/13.mp4 -i /Users/andaegeun/Desktop/theirmood/theirmood/storage/app/public/videoAddAnimation/14.mp4 -i /Users/andaegeun/Desktop/theirmood/theirmood/storage/app/public/videoAddAnimation/15.mp4 -i /Users/andaegeun/Desktop/theirmood/theirmood/storage/app/public/videoAddAnimation/16.mp4 -i /Users/andaegeun/Desktop/theirmood/theirmood/storage/app/public/videoAddAnimation/17.mp4 -i /Users/andaegeun/Desktop/theirmood/theirmood/storage/app/public/videoAddAnimation/18.mp4 -i /Users/andaegeun/Desktop/theirmood/theirmood/storage/app/public/videoAddAnimation/19.mp4 -i /Users/andaegeun/Desktop/theirmood/theirmood/storage/app/public/videoAddAnimation/20.mp4 -i /Users/andaegeun/Desktop/theirmood/theirmood/storage/app/public/videoAddAnimation/21.mp4 -i /Users/andaegeun/Desktop/theirmood/theirmood/storage/app/public/videoAddAnimation/22.mp4 -i /Users/andaegeun/Desktop/theirmood/theirmood/storage/app/public/videoAddAnimation/23.mp4 -i /Users/andaegeun/Desktop/theirmood/theirmood/storage/app/public/videoAddAnimation/24.mp4 -i /Users/andaegeun/Desktop/theirmood/theirmood/storage/app/public/videoAddAnimation/25.mp4 -i /Users/andaegeun/Desktop/theirmood/theirmood/storage/app/public/videoAddAnimation/26.mp4 -i /Users/andaegeun/Desktop/theirmood/theirmood/storage/app/public/videoAddAnimation/27.mp4 -i /Users/andaegeun/Desktop/theirmood/theirmood/storage/app/public/videoAddAnimation/28.mp4 -i /Users/andaegeun/Desktop/theirmood/theirmood/storage/app/public/videoAddAnimation/29.mp4 -i /Users/andaegeun/Desktop/theirmood/theirmood/storage/app/public/videoAddAnimation/30.mp4 -i /Users/andaegeun/Desktop/theirmood/theirmood/storage/app/public/videoAddAnimation/31.mp4 -i /Users/andaegeun/Desktop/theirmood/theirmood/storage/app/public/videoAddAnimation/32.mp4 -i /Users/andaegeun/Desktop/theirmood/theirmood/storage/app/public/videoAddAnimation/33.mp4 -i /Users/andaegeun/Desktop/theirmood/theirmood/storage/app/public/videoAddAnimation/34.mp4 -i /Users/andaegeun/Desktop/theirmood/theirmood/storage/app/public/videoAddAnimation/35.mp4 -i /Users/andaegeun/Desktop/theirmood/theirmood/storage/app/public/videoAddAnimation/36.mp4 -i /Users/andaegeun/Desktop/theirmood/theirmood/storage/app/public/videoAddAnimation/37.mp4 -filter_complex "[0][1]xfade=transition=fade:duration=2:offset=4[1];[1][2]xfade=transition=fade:duration=2:offset=9[2];[2][3]xfade=transition=fade:duration=2:offset=15[3];[3][4]xfade=transition=fade:duration=2:offset=20[4];[4][5]xfade=transition=fade:duration=2:offset=24[5];[5][6]xfade=transition=fade:duration=2:offset=27[6];[6][7]xfade=transition=fade:duration=2:offset=30[7];[7][8]xfade=transition=fade:duration=2:offset=33[8];[8][9]xfade=transition=fade:duration=2:offset=37[9];[9][10]xfade=transition=fade:duration=2:offset=42[10];[10][11]xfade=transition=fade:duration=2:offset=46[11];[11][12]xfade=transition=fade:duration=2:offset=51[12];[12][13]xfade=transition=fade:duration=2:offset=57[13];[13][14]xfade=transition=fade:duration=2:offset=62[14];[14][15]xfade=transition=fade:duration=2:offset=66[15];[15][16]xfade=transition=fade:duration=2:offset=69[16];[16][17]xfade=transition=fade:duration=2:offset=72[17];[17][18]xfade=transition=fade:duration=2:offset=75[18];[18][19]xfade=transition=fade:duration=2:offset=79[19];[19][20]xfade=transition=fade:duration=2:offset=84[20];[20][21]xfade=transition=fade:duration=2:offset=88[21];[21][22]xfade=transition=fade:duration=2:offset=93[22];[22][23]xfade=transition=fade:duration=2:offset=99[23];[23][24]xfade=transition=fade:duration=2:offset=104[24];[24][25]xfade=transition=fade:duration=2:offset=108[25];[25][26]xfade=transition=fade:duration=2:offset=111[26];[26][27]xfade=transition=fade:duration=2:offset=114[27];[27][28]xfade=transition=fade:duration=2:offset=117[28];[28][29]xfade=transition=fade:duration=2:offset=121[29];[29][30]xfade=transition=fade:duration=2:offset=126[30];[30][31]xfade=transition=fade:duration=2:offset=130[31];[31][32]xfade=transition=fade:duration=2:offset=135[32];[32][33]xfade=transition=fade:duration=2:offset=141[33];[33][34]xfade=transition=fade:duration=2:offset=146[34];[34][35]xfade=transition=fade:duration=2:offset=150[35];[35][36]xfade=transition=fade:duration=2:offset=153[36];[36][37]xfade=transition=fade:duration=2:offset=156,format=yuv420p" -y /Users/andaegeun/Desktop/theirmood/theirmood/storage/app/public/mergeAndTransition/transition.mp4`
```

error

```
`Stream mapping:   Stream #0:0 (h264) -> xfade   Stream #1:0 (h264) -> xfade   Stream #2:0 (h264) -> xfade   Stream #3:0 (h264) -> xfade   Stream #4:0 (h264) -> xfade   Stream #5:0 (h264) -> xfade   Stream #6:0 (h264) -> xfade   Stream #7:0 (h264) -> xfade   Stream #8:0 (h264) -> xfade   Stream #9:0 (h264) -> xfade   Stream #10:0 (h264) -> xfade   Stream #11:0 (h264) -> xfade   Stream #12:0 (h264) -> xfade   Stream #13:0 (h264) -> xfade   Stream #14:0 (h264) -> xfade   Stream #15:0 (h264) -> xfade   Stream #16:0 (h264) -> xfade   Stream #17:0 (h264) -> xfade   Stream #18:0 (h264) -> xfade   Stream #19:0 (h264) -> xfade   Stream #20:0 (h264) -> xfade   Stream #21:0 (h264) -> xfade   Stream #22:0 (h264) -> xfade   Stream #23:0 (h264) -> xfade   Stream #24:0 (h264) -> xfade   Stream #25:0 (h264) -> xfade   Stream #26:0 (h264) -> xfade   Stream #27:0 (h264) -> xfade   Stream #28:0 (h264) -> xfade   Stream #29:0 (h264) -> xfade   Stream #30:0 (h264) -> xfade   Stream #31:0 (h264) -> xfade   Stream #32:0 (h264) -> xfade   Stream #33:0 (h264) -> xfade   Stream #34:0 (h264) -> xfade   Stream #35:0 (h264) -> xfade   Stream #36:0 (h264) -> xfade   Stream #37:0 (h264) -> xfade   format:default -> Stream #0:0 (libx264) Press [q] to stop, [?] for help [swscaler @ 0x7fc297d65000] [swscaler @ 0x7fc297d72000] deprecated pixel format used, make sure you did set range correctly [swscaler @ 0x7fc297d65000] [swscaler @ 0x7fc297d7f000] deprecated pixel format used, make sure you did set range correctly [swscaler @ 0x7fc297d65000] [swscaler @ 0x7fc297d8c000] deprecated pixel format used, make sure you did set range correctly [swscaler @ 0x7fc297d65000] [swscaler @ 0x7fc297d99000] deprecated pixel format used, make sure you did set range correctly [swscaler @ 0x7fc297d65000] [swscaler @ 0x7fc297da6000] deprecated pixel format used, make sure you did set range correctly [swscaler @ 0x7fc297d65000] [swscaler @ 0x7fc297db3000] deprecated pixel format used, make sure you did set range correctly [swscaler @ 0x7fc297d65000] [swscaler @ 0x7fc297dc0000] deprecated pixel format used, make sure you did set range correctly [swscaler @ 0x7fc297d65000] [swscaler @ 0x7fc297dcd000] deprecated pixel format used, make sure you did set range correctly [swscaler @ 0x7fc297d65000] [swscaler @ 0x7fc297dda000] deprecated pixel format used, make sure you did set range correctly [swscaler @ 0x7fc297de7000] [swscaler @ 0x7fc297df4000] deprecated pixel format used, make sure you did set range correctly [swscaler @ 0x7fc297de7000] [swscaler @ 0x7fc297e01000] deprecated pixel format used, make sure you did set range correctly [swscaler @ 0x7fc297de7000] [swscaler @ 0x7fc297e0e000] deprecated pixel format used, make sure you did set range correctly [swscaler @ 0x7fc297de7000] [swscaler @ 0x7fc297e1b000] deprecated pixel format used, make sure you did set range correctly [swscaler @ 0x7fc297de7000] [swscaler @ 0x7fc297e28000] deprecated pixel format used, make sure you did set range correctly [swscaler @ 0x7fc297de7000] [swscaler @ 0x7fc297e35000] deprecated pixel format used, make sure you did set range correctly [swscaler @ 0x7fc297de7000] [swscaler @ 0x7fc297e42000] deprecated pixel format used, make sure you did set range correctly [swscaler @ 0x7fc297de7000] [swscaler @ 0x7fc297e4f000] deprecated pixel format used, make sure you did set range correctly [swscaler @ 0x7fc297de7000] [swscaler @ 0x7fc297e5c000] deprecated pixel format used, make sure you did set range correctly [swscaler @ 0x7fc297e69000] [swscaler @ 0x7fc297e76000] deprecated pixel format used, make sure you did set range correctly [swscaler @ 0x7fc297e69000] [swscaler @ 0x7fc297e83000] deprecated pixel format used, make sure you did set range correctly [swscaler @ 0x7fc297e69000] [swscaler @ 0x7fc297e90000] deprecated pixel format used, make sure you did set range correctly [swscaler @ 0x7fc297e69000] [swscaler @ 0x7fc297e9d000] deprecated pixel format used, make sure you did set range correctly [swscaler @ 0x7fc297e69000] [swscaler @ 0x7fc297eaa000] deprecated pixel format used, make sure you did set range correctly [swscaler @ 0x7fc297e69000] [swscaler @ 0x7fc297eb7000] deprecated pixel format used, make sure you did set range correctly [swscaler @ 0x7fc297e69000] [swscaler @ 0x7fc297ec4000] deprecated pixel format used, make sure you did set range correctly [swscaler @ 0x7fc297e69000] [swscaler @ 0x7fc297ed1000] deprecated pixel format used, make sure you did set range correctly [swscaler @ 0x7fc297e69000] [swscaler @ 0x7fc297ede000] deprecated pixel format used, make sure you did set range correctly
```

`[Parsed_xfade_0 @ 0x7fc2e81aed80] [IMGUTILS @ 0x7ffee7b05cd8] Picture size 0x0 is invalid Error reinitializing filters! Failed to inject frame into filter network: Invalid argument Error while processing the decoded data for stream #37:0 Conversion failed!`

Comment: `Picture size 0x0 is invalid ... for stream #37:0` Your video 37.mp4 has zero resolution

Answer (score 0):

the problem is format=yuv420p, or remove it like option one, or use correct in 2dn option, choice:

- 1. use format=yuv420p but when the first video was done
- 2. if you want to do all in one work add format=yuv420p in every
     stream like

     [1][2]xfade=transition=fade:duration=2:offset=9[2],format=yuv420p;[2][3]xfade=transition=fade:duration=2:offset=15[3],format=yuv420p;[3][4]xfade=transition=fade:duration=2:offset=20[4],format=yuv420p;
     continue...